# How to check circleci credit usage per repository?

Tags: continuous-integration, circleci, credits

I'm using circle CI to handle testing and deployment for my projects, but evidently I am running out of credits. How to check which repository that consume the biggest credit?  And can I disable some workflows/commands if my credit below a certain number? An example I disable browser test workflow if my credit below 5000.